# Validation Error on one Environment but not on the other

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

We have two Servers. One Windows 2008 and one Windows 2012. On both servers there is a domino Server (2008 - without fixpacks and 2012 - with fixpack 10). On the domino servers there are identical Xpages with identical customcontrols.

On the Windows 2008 Server everything works fine. On the 2012 Server we get a validation error on a number input which is a currency field. It says "This field is not a valid number" from server side validation.

I assume that it might have to do with the language setting on the server which is on the 2008 "Deutsch(Deutsch)" and on 2012 Germany(Germany).

Anyone has experience with Server settings in relation to server side validation?

-------Update-------

In the 2008 environment the converter looks like this:

```
<xp:this.converter>
    <xp:convertNumber type="currency"
        currencySymbol="€">
    </xp:convertNumber>
</xp:this.converter>
```

I changed code in the 2012 environment to this:

```
<xp:this.converter>
    <xp:convertNumber type="currency">
    </xp:convertNumber>
</xp:this.converter>
```

And it seems to work. On the browser everything looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check the decimal separator on the two servers. It's possible that may be different. It may also be a problem caused by currency symbol. Without knowing what values you've tried, it's hard to advise.

Comment: Decimal separator is the same in region settings on both servers. This value: "5.490,00 €" would fail and either this would fail: "610,00 €" (widthout apostrophe)

Comment: Updated the question but can´t explain it.